# Disable see through in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I am drawing with grease pencil, I've noticed that I can see through it depending on the angle, which I don't want (second image), I know I can disable that by choosing 3d location for stroke depth color, but that messes up the drawing. Is there any other way?

[image]

[image]